# Multiple Object detection from Single Image ( training without bounding box)

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, yolo

I have some high-quality images that have multiple objects in single image and label. No Bounding box is given in training data. I can manually draw bounding box and train it. But it is **time-consuming**. So I am asking if there any machine learning algorithm which can be trained **without any bounding box.**
Could anyone give any suggestion ??

Comment: You forgot to mention the task you want to do, if its image classification, you don't need bounding boxes.

Comment: Yes, I treat it as an image classification problem for multiple objects primarily. I may add bounding box later. so you mean I can use any image classification techniques like CNN for classification only?

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer to your question: **NO**

The problem will become unsupervised for object localization and will lead to no good solution; or either you could treat your problem as multi-label image classification if you want.

Comment: thank you,  does multi-label image classification lead to a good accuracy if my architecture is good enough for training?

Comment: You should go for transfer learning in this case. Take a pre-trained network and fine tune it on your dataset, libraries like Tensorflow Hub can take you to destination.

Comment: thanks, brother. I am using inception v3 now, initial accuracy is quite good.